# Consume asmx service in azure function

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, asmx

We are looking to call/consume old asmx web service(which we do not have any control over) from azure function

Is it possible? If yes how can we do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is it accessible over an HTTP endpoint ? If so, use an HttpClient instance to call it ?

Comment: @Shyju yes it is available... It on https !

Comment: Use IHttpClientFactory to get an HttpClient instance and make the call then. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Shyju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40521/shyju). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

**Typed Client** is just an `HttpClient` that's pre-configured for some specific use. This configuration can include specific values such as the base server, HTTP headers or time outs.

Below diagram will help you in understanding how Typed Clients are used with `IHttpClientFactory`

[image]

Below code can be used as Typed Client Class

```
namespace Microsoft.eShopOnContainers.WebMVC.Controllers
{
    public class CatalogController : Controller
    {
        private ICatalogService _catalogSvc;

        public CatalogController(ICatalogService catalogSvc) =>
                                                           _catalogSvc = catalogSvc;

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? BrandFilterApplied,
                                               int? TypesFilterApplied,
                                               int? page,
                                               [FromQuery]string errorMsg)
        {
            var itemsPage = 10;
            var catalog = await _catalogSvc.GetCatalogItems(page ?? 0,
                                                            itemsPage,
                                                            BrandFilterApplied,
                                                            TypesFilterApplied);
            //… Additional code
        }

        }
}
```